# Using other browser scripting libraries alongside Mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize

I have a task where I have to upload around 1,500 PDF files to a Drupal CMS.  I cannot upload them all at once because, at least for the Drupal build we're using, uploading a file is a drawn out process, rather than just a single page form.  Obviously I want to automate this.  I have been attempting to write a script to accomplish this task.

With Mechanize, I have successfully logged into the CMS and navigated to the 'node' creation page.  However, the process of uploading a file required clicking a button, which opens up an embedded window, in which you click another button that opens up the directory window to select the file, then two confirmation windows before you're back on the original page to submit the form.  There is generally some significant lag between the embedded windows loading.

Is there a way I can incorporate any Python web testing libraries (like Splinter) in with the Mechanize session I've already created?  Or would it be best to rewrite the script using entirely different libraries?

Python script:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser(factory = mechanize.RobustFactory())
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br.set_handle_equiv(True) 
br.set_handle_redirect(True) 
br.set_handle_referer(True) 
br.set_handle_robots(False)

def authenticate():
    print 'Attepting to log in to CMS...'
    br.open('url')
    br.form = list(br.forms())[2]
    br['name'] = 'name'
    br['pass'] = 'pass'
    br['usage-accept'] = ['1']
    try:
        br.submit()
        print 'Success!'
    except:
        'Login failed.  Is the VPN active?'

def downloadselection():
    print 'Navigating to download page...'
    br.open('next url')
    print 'Success!'

def selectcategory():
    print 'Selecting appropriate download category...'
    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    br['gid'] = ['286']
    br.submit()
    print 'Success!'
    print 'Filling out forms...'
    br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
    br['title'] = 'test'
    br['body[und][0][summary]'] = 'test'
    br['body[und][0][value]'] = 'test'
    print 'Success! Selecting file to upload...'

    #print 'Success!'exit

if __name__ == '__main__':

    authenticate()
    downloadselection()
    selectcategory()
```

The HTML source on the page that handles the upload button looks like so:

```
</div><a class="button launcher" href="#">Select media</a>
```

Then the embedded window is a `<div id=media-browser-page>` with an `<input id="edit-upload">` element.

Sorry, this is a jumble of information, but I'm pretty lost and I'm not sure how to integrate another library with Mechanize.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) is definitely the option to consider.

Comment: Yes, that's sort of the last resort, as this has been a good learning project for me and I'd love to work out a way to hand script the whole thing, rather than recording my actions in Selenium.